# fnDestroy() + invalid argument line 200 datatables.min.js+ IE + JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery datatables. On button click I have to reinitialize the datatables so what I am doing on button click is as follows:

```
function clearHeaderData() 
{
   $('#companies').dataTable().empty();
   $('#companies').dataTable().fnDestroy();
   makeTableClear(); //here I creating new datatable. I call it wherever I need to create dataTable.

}
```

**Problem:**

When I click the button, clearHeaderData() is called and throws an error "Invalid Argument" on fnDestroy();
The error location is jquery.dataTables.min.js Line:200 CHAR:265 which contains following code:

```
 a.nTable.insertBefore(i, a.nTable.childNodes[0]);
```

**The problem only occurs in IE. It works fine in chrome and firefox.**

I read a lot about it on Google but nothing worked. Hope to find guidance by you people.

Regards,
Misbah.

```
function makeTableClear()
            {
$( "#formAddNewRow" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: 'Please fill the form:', width: 520, height: 480, modal: true });

         //   alert("in clear table");
             $("#companies").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": false,
            //sScrollY: '250px',
            //sScrollX: '750px',
            //"sAjaxSource": "public_html/ajax/data/arrays.txt",
           // "sAjaxSource": "http://127.0.0.1:7101/CURDExample-CURDViewController-context-root/CompanyAjaxDataSource",
            //"sAjaxSource": "http://127.0.0.1:7101/HSEApplication-ViewController-context-root/FireFightingServlet",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bDestroy": true, 
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "150%",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false, // Disable the auto width calculation
            "aoColumns": [
                          {  "sName": "ID",
                             "bSearchable": false,
                             "bSortable": false,
                             "bVisible": false
                                 },
                  {  "sName": "Type" },
                  { "sName": "Location" }, 
                  { "sName": "Easily Accessible" },
                  { "sName": "Operating Instruction Visible" },
                  {  "sName": "Safety Seal" },
                  { "sName": "Fulness Determined By" },                 
                  { "sName": "Pressure Gauge" },
                  { "sName": "Cylinder Condition" },
                  {  "sName": "Nozzle/Hose Pipe Condition" },
                  { "sName": "Tires Condition" },                 
                  { "sName": "Status" },
                  { "sName": "Conducted By" }
                 ]      

     }).makeEditable({
            sAddURL: "../FireFightingDetailServlet?action=addDetail",//&HID="+document.getElementById("headerId").value,
            sUpdateURL: "../FireFightingDetailServlet?action=updateDetail",
           sDeleteURL: "../FireFightingDetailServlet?action=deleteDetail",
             fnShowError: function (message, action) 
             {
                    switch (action) {
                    case "update":
                            if (message=="")alert("Update successful");
                            else alert(message);
                            break;
                    default: alert(message);

                    }
                },

                "aoColumns": [
                         {
                              //cssclass: "required"
                                  indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'You may change the field by double click ',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                                  data: '{"CO2":"CO2","DCP":"DCP","AFFF": "AFFF","Water":"Water"}'
                          },//null for read-only columns
                                {
                              cssclass: "required",
                                  indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'You may change the field by double click ',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'text',
                              onblur: 'submit'
                                },

                            {
                              //cssclass: "required"
                                  indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'You may change the field by double click ',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                                  data: '{"Yes":"Yes","No":"No"}'
                          },
                          {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                                  data: '{"Yes":"Yes","No":"No"}'
                          },

                          {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                              data: '{"Ok":"Ok","Missing":"Missing","Broken": "Broken"}'
                          },
                              {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                              data: '{"Weighing":"Weighing","Pressure Gauge":"Pressure Gauge"}'
                          },
                              {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                              data: '{"Green":"Green","Red":"Red"}'
                          },
                              {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                              data: '{"Ok":"Ok","Not Ok":"Not Ok"}'
                          },
                              {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                              data: '{"Ok":"Ok","Not Ok":"Not Ok"}'
                          },
                              {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                              data: '{"Ok":"Ok","Not Ok":"Not Ok","N/A":"N/A"}'
                          },
                              {
                              indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'select',
                              onblur: 'submit',
                              data: '{"Fit":"Fit","Not Fit":"Not Fit","Pending":"Pending"}'
                          },//null for read-only columns
                              {
                              cssclass: "required",
                                  indicator: 'Saving...',
                              tooltip: 'You may change the field by double click ',
                              loadtext: 'loading...',
                              type: 'text',
                              onblur: 'submit'
                               }
                      ]


                    }); 
            }
```

Comment: What version of dataTables? What are you doing in `makeTableClear()` ..?

Comment: Version? I am unable to locate. I am using code from this link. Hope you'll the version and please let me know too. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193068/Adding-data-management-CRUD-functionalities-to-the

Comment: I cannot see which exactly, I have to login to download the package, but it seems defently to be an older 1.9.x version or even older. But again, what are you doing in makeTableClear() ...

Comment: function makeTableClear() { $("#companies").dataTable({ "bServerSide": false,  "bProcessing": true, "bRetrieve": true,
"bDestroy": true,  "bAutoWidth": false,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sScrollX": "100%",
"sScrollXInner": "150%",
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"bAutoWidth": false, // Disable the auto width calculation
aoColumns": [bla bla bla}]      
 }).makeEditable({
 sAddURL: "../FireFightingDetailServlet?action=addDetail",
 }}, "aoColumns": [bla bla bla ]]});}

Comment: I deleted some code from makeTableClear() because the site does not allow me to add this much long code in comment.

Comment: You should also [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33913676/edit) your question, not add code in comments :) The link is a link to the small `share|edit|close|flag` menu below your question. I know this can be a surprise to new users - welcome to stackoverflow anyway!

Comment: Done. Thanks :) Solution?? :/

Comment: what does `i` and ` a.nTable.childNodes[0]`evaluate to when the exception is thrown?

Comment: In normal case: i=[object HTML TableSectionElement] and a.nTable.childNodes[0]=[objact Text]

Comment: when exception thrown: 1=[object HTML TableSectionElement]  and a.nTable.childNodes[0]=undefined

Comment: still looking for some solution :/